# Is ld.so an executable?

Tags: load, linker

```
$ file /lib/ld-linux.so.2
/lib/ld-linux.so.2: symbolic link to i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
$ readlink -f /lib/ld-linux.so.2
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
$ file /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=7a59ed1836f27b66ffd391d656da6435055f02f8, stripped
```

So is `ld-2.27.so`  a shared library?

[It is said to be a dynamic linker/loader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1952986/156458) and [mentioned in section 8  of man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html). So is it  an executable?

If yes, why is it named like a shared library as `*.so`?

If no, how shall I understand it is like an executable, for being a  dynamic linker/loader and mentioned in section 8  of man?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is both, [which is perfectly valid](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/223385/86440).

The `ld.so`-style naming scheme is largely historical; the first dynamic linker in this style was SunOS 4’s, which was named `ld.so` (I have its history somewhere, I’ll clarify this once I’ve found it). But there are valid reasons for it to be named like a shared library rather than an executable, including:

- it exists to serve executables, like shared libraries (it has no purpose without executables to run);
- it is a shared ELF object, but it doesn’t require an interpreter (it has no `.interp` entry); this is typical of libraries (shared, or rather dynamically-linked, executables always require an interpreter; otherwise they’re statically-linked).

The distinction between executables and libraries is somewhat fluid in ELF; any ELF object with an entry point and/or an interpreter can be an executable, regardless of its other properties.

Comment: Did you happen to find that naming history?

Comment: @ilkkachu not yet...

Comment: (1) "shared executables always require an interpreter; otherwise they’re static, not dynamic". Do you mean "shared **libraries** always require an interpreter; otherwise they’re static, not dynamic"? What makes an ELF object file become a shared library file? (Does having .interp entry  make an ELF object file become a shared library file? ) (2) What makes an ELF object file become a static library file? (Or is a static library file  not an ELF object file, but an archive of relocatable object files?)

Comment: (1) I mean what I wrote. Executables have interpreters (if they’re dynamically linked), not libraries. Some libraries are also executable files, *e.g.* `libc.so.6` (see the link in the first paragraph). An ELF object file is a shared library if its type is `ET_DYN`. (2) A static library is an archive of relocatable object files.

Comment: Thanks. "it doesn’t require an interpreter (it has no .interp entry); this is typical of **libraries** (**shared executables** always require an interpreter; otherwise they’re static, not dynamic)." What does "this is typical of libraries" mean then? Do you mean a  library (a shared library) must have or typically has  .interp entry?

Comment: It is typical for shared libraries *not to require* an interpreter. What is typical is the entire first part: “it doesn’t require an interpreter (it has no .interp entry)”.

Comment: (1) "Executables have interpreters (if they’re dynamically linked), not libraries. "  Do executables which are not dynamically linked have .interp? Does any executable  have both .interp and entry point? (2)  "libraries are also executable files", for such files, are their ELF types ELF_DYN, not ELF_EXEC? So  does "executable" here not mean that its ELF type is ELF_EXEC, but that it has .interp and entry point?

Comment: (1) Executables which are not dynamically-linked don’t have `.interp`. Executables always have an entry point. (2) I’ve answered this already. Libraries always have type `ET_DYN`. Executables can have type `ET_EXEC` or `ET_DYN`; they always have an entry point, and tjey have `.interp` if they are dynamically-linked.