# what are the executable ELF files respectively for static linker, dynamic linker, loader and dynamic loader?

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, load, linker, dynamic-loading

In Linux, what are the executable ELF files respectively for

- static linker
- dynamic linker
- loader
- dynamic loader?

Which of them are invoked

- by `execve()`
- by `dlopen()`?

How are they invoked by `execve()` or `dlopen()`, to solve the chicken-egg problem that `execve()` or `dlopen()` are used for invoking executable files?

Thanks.

Comment: grammar understand I not make sense random words.

Comment: What doesn't make sense? @c

Answer (score 7):

I take it you’re using [Jeff Darcy’s definitions](https://www.quora.com/Systems-Programming/What-is-the-exact-difference-between-dynamic-loading-and-dynamic-linking/answer/Jeff-Darcy):

- static linking involves resolving symbols at compile time, whereas dynamic linking involves resolving them at run time;
- static loading involves mapping the executable and libraries at load time, whereas dynamic loading involves mapping the libraries after the process has started.

It doesn’t really make sense to try to split everything up; instead, you should consider the pairs of features:

- static loading, static linking: the linker is `/usr/bin/ld` typically, along with static libraries (`.a`); the loader is the kernel;
- static loading, dynamic linking: the linker is `/usr/bin/ld` again, but with shared libraries (`.so`); the loader is the binary’s interpreter, *e.g.* `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` (which maps to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so` currently) on Debian 9 on 64-bit x86, itself loaded by the kernel, which also loads the main executable;
- dynamic loading, static linking: this isn’t used on Linux as far as I’m aware;
- dynamic loading, dynamic linking: the loader is a library such as `libdl`; the linker is split between the library and the program calling `libdl`.

Perhaps some more explanation is called for in relation to the last point. When a program uses `libdl` to load a library, it calls [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), which loads the named library, along with any of its dependencies which aren’t already available in the process, and links the named library with its dependencies. Thus `libdl` performs both loading (of the necessary libraries) and linking (of the libraries only, not the calling program). When the calling program needs to use a symbol from the named library, it calls [`dlsym`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)  which returns the address of the requested symbol (if it can find it). Thus the calling program performs part of the linking.

There is no chicken-and-egg problem with regards to `execve` or `dlopen`. Programs compiled to use `execve` are compiled with the appropriate references to `libc` (which contains the wrapper most programs actually use) and the `execve` symbol (strictly speaking, the aforementioned wrapper). Those references are resolved either at compile-time (for statically-linked programs) or at load-time (for dynamically-linked programs); after that, the symbol is available for use and the program can call `execve`. The same goes for `dlopen`: programs which want to use `dlopen` are compiled with the appropriate references to `libdl` and `dlopen`. The dynamic linker itself is a static binary, so the kernel can load it without the help of the dynamic linker. You’ll find lots more detail on this topic in [How programs get run](https://lwn.net/Articles/630727/) and [How programs get run: ELF binaries](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/).

(Note that in all cases of dynamic *linking*, if lazy binding is enabled, linking can happen just-in-time, and not necessarily at load time.)

Comment: Thanks. "the loader is the binary’s interpreter", do you mean the loader that loads a shared library by "the loader", and the loader for the executable is always the kernel? What is "the binary", and is it the shared library? Does a shared library need to be interpreted, and I think only scripts or executable need to be interpreted.

Comment: The “binary” is the program being run; it is loaded by the kernel, but it is linked by the dynamic linker (the program’s interpreter), which also loads (and links) any required libraries. The “loader” for the libraries is thus the dynamic linker (this is getting confusing). Shared libraries typically don’t have an interpreter, but they can.

Comment: "The dynamic linker itself is a static binary, so the kernel can load it without the help of the dynamic linker."   Do you mean `ld-linux.so` by  dynamic linker? What does "static binary" mean? (According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448937/is-ld-so-an-executable, `ld-linux.so` is both an executable and a shared library file, not a static library.)

Comment: I’m referring to `ld-linux.so`. By “static binary” I meant one which doesn’t need any shared library in order to run. `ld-linux.so` is indeed both a shared library and an executable, but it doesn’t need any other shared library to run (although it does allow symbol replacement, so it’s not fully statically-linked; IIRC I’ve written more about that in another Q&A).