# What is "arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.24.so"?

Tags: linux, bash, glibc

When i

```
$ file /bin/bash
```

on my raspberry, it says

```
interpreter arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.24.so
```

Is it an "ELF shared object" or a "binary program as Dynamic linker"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what are the executable ELF files respectively for static linker, dynamic linker, loader and dynamic loader?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476780/what-are-the-executable-elf-files-respectively-for-static-linker-dynamic-linker)

Comment: Yes a dynamically linked shared object (library). It is the loader, that loads the program.