# What is the linker and what is the loader in dynamic linking?

Tags: shared-library, dynamic-linking, ld

[Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective (3ed)](https://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/) says on p733 that

> **7.9 Loading Executable Object Files**
>
> To run an executable object ﬁle prog, we can type its name to the Linux shell’s command line:
>
> linux> ./prog
>
> Since `prog` does not correspond to a built-in shell command, the shell assumes that `prog` is an executable object ﬁle, which it runs for us by invoking some memory-resident operating system code known as **the loader**. Any Linux program can invoke the loader by calling the `execve` function, which we will describe in detail in Section 8.4.6

and in p736: during dynamic linking

> **7.10 Dynamic Linking with Shared Libraries**
>
> Once we have created the library, we would then link it into our example
> program in Figure 7.7:
>
> ```
> linux> gcc -o prog2l main2.c ./libvector.so
> ```
>
> This creates an executable object ﬁle `prog2l` in a form that can be linked with `libvector.so` at run time. The basic idea is to do some of the linking statically when the executable ﬁle is created, and then complete the linking process dynamically when the program is loaded. It is important to realize that **none of the code or data sections from libvector.so are actually copied into the executable `prog2l`** at this point. Instead, **the linker copies some relocation and symbol table information** that will allow references to code and data in `libvector.so` to be resolved at load time.
>
> When the loader loads and runs the executable `prog2l`, it loads the partially
> linked executable `prog2l`, using the techniques discussed in Section 7.9. Next, it
> notices that `prog2l` contains a `.interp` section, which contains the path name of
> the dynamic linker, which is itself a shared object (e.g., `ld-linux.so` on Linux
> systems). Instead of passing control to the application, as it would normally do,
> the loader loads and runs the dynamic linker.
> **The dynamic linker** then ﬁnishes **the linking task** by performing the following relocations:
>
> - Relocating the text and data of `libc.so` into some memory segment
> - Relocating the text and data of `libvector.so` into another memory segment
> - Relocating any references in `prog2l` to symbols deﬁned by `libc.so` and
>   `libvector.so`

The above dynamic linking case is  the "static loading, dynamic linking" case in [Stephen Kitt's reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476783/674):

> static loading, dynamic linking: **the linker** is /usr/bin/ld again, but with shared libraries (.so); **the loader** is the binary’s interpreter, e.g. /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (which maps to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so currently) on Debian 9 on 64-bit x86, itself loaded by the kernel, which also loads the main executable;

The difference is that CSAPP seems to say that  the loader is (the kernel code behind) `execve()` and the linker is `ld-linux.so` (no linking happens at compile time by `ld`, and actual linking happens at load time by `ld-linux.so`).

What is the linker and what is the loader in dynamic linking?

Thanks.

Comment: Why was this downvoted 4 times? The only issue I see is that CSAPP wasn't properly introduced as an acronym. Otherwise, this seems like a totally valid question for this SE site.

Answer (score 1):

The highlighting here:

> **The dynamic linker** then ﬁnishes **the linking task**

misses the important word, “**finishes**”. The linker, `ld`, starts the linking task, performing as much as possible at build-time and preparing the data structures required to finish it.

The loader can then finish the linking task as it loads the program and the libraries it needs: matching up symbols, and performing the necessary relocation.

In CSAPP’s terminology, the dynamic loader is the in-kernel ELF loader, and the dynamic linker is `ld-linux.so`.

The GNU C library’s own documentation refers to `ld.so` as [the dynamic linker/loader](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html). `ld.so` (or `ld-linux.so`) performs quite a lot of loading itself, as well as linking, so applying both terms to it is accurate — the kernel loads the executable itself and its interpreter (the dynamic linker/loader), and the interpreter loads all the other required libraries.

See [How programs get run: ELF binaries](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/) for details of how this all works on Linux systems.

Comment: Does the manpage of ld.so say that ld.so is both the loader and linker of a shared library, during dynamic linking?

Comment: Does your reply https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476783/674 need some change?

Comment: `ld.so` and `ld-linux.so` are the same thing. The manpage says that `ld.so` is both the loader and linker of dynamically-linked executables. I don’t think my existing answer needs to be changed just because CSAPP uses different terminology.

Comment: "In CSAPP’s terminology, the dynamic loader is the in-kernel ELF loader" (I think you meant static loader by "dynamic loader" https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476783), and "The GNU C library’s own documentation refers to ld.so as the dynamic linker/loader." In dynamic linking (with static loading), is the loader both the in-kernel ELF loader and ld.so? Are they the same thing? What is the in-kernel ELF loader?

Comment: Does execve() perform static loading of shared libraries (needed by the executable which is its first argument), by invoking ld-linux.so?

Comment: Yes, static loader in Jeff Darcy’s classification, sorry (it gets confusing for everyone). The kernel loader is [`binfmt_elf.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c) in Linux. It can load statically-linked binaries on its own, but for dynamically-linked binaries it needs `ld-linux.so`’s help. `execve` doesn’t perform any static loading of libraries, it delegates all that to the dynamic linker.

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic linker is call `ld.so`. You can find the configuration under `/etc/ld.so*`. Most of the configuration has to do with paths where .so are to be searched.

`ld` has to make sure that all the functions exist in the shared libraries before finishing up the linking of an executable (well... technically, it is not required to do so, but it does—that being said, if you copy an executable from one computer to another, the .so could be different and have new functions and have lost old ones and the binary won't run).

When the linker (`ld`) creates a binary which expects a shared library, it keeps a certain number of symbols and corresponding addresses in your `.text` section. That's what the dynamic linker (`ld.so`) uses to finish up the linking at run time. It will search the symbols in the corresponding .so files and save their addresses wherever required in your code (for functions, it is often a table of `jump` instructions so that way they can link each function only once).

And of course, when you strip a binary, those *special symbols* do not get removed.

To see the list of libraries that will be loaded, you can run `ldd` against your executable. Especially, it will show you which .so is selected to resolve the symbols (full path). You can change the search path with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. That allows you to test against different or uninstalled .so files (cmake, automake do use the `--rpath` as well, which is the same, only the path is saved directly in the binaries).

Which part exactly loads the files and kickstarts them, I'm not exactly sure. The `execve()` is probably not directly implementing all of that logic. But it is certainly close to the lowest level function that knows how to run an executable.

So in effect, the dynamic linking is an *extremely simple* process compared to the standard linker:

1. load the .so
2. search the .so for symbols
3. save symbol address

Done. This is why it's so fast.

**Note:** Further dynamism can be achieved using the `dlopen()`, but it sounds like you're not talking about that part.

Comment: If I am correct, `ldd` is to report what shared libraries a partially linked executable file needs. It is not a linker.

Comment: `ldd` *uses* the dynamic linker, `ld.so` (or `ld-linux.so`), but it isn’t itself the dynamic linker.

Comment: @Tim & Stephen, I've edited my post with the correction. I've applied a few other corrections too.