# Is loader for a particular "executable format" configurable in Linux?

Tags: gnu, ld

This question is in continuation of  [How does compiler lay out code in memory,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101449/how-does-compiler-lay-out-code-in-memory#)
 which is posted at stack-overflow.

I have few questions with respect to `ld` (GNU) utility available in Linux.

Whenever a program is run in the shell, say `./a.out`, the shell uses `ld` to load the program represented by `a.out`.

1. How does the shell know it has to use `ld` to load `a.out`. Does it scan the `a.out` to check if it is in the ELF format and if so, uses `ld`? It certainly can't use the file name extension, since there is no rule to name executable's in a certain format.
2. Can `ld` utility load programs represented in any other executable formats other than ELF?
3. Suppose I come up with my own executable format, say "xyz" and I write my own loader `abc` which handles such executables. Then, is there any shell command to configure: "use loader `abc` to load program compiled in a particular executable format "xyz"?

Comment: You might be interested in [binfmt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The shell doesn’t know, the kernel does. See [What types of executable files exist on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/511790/86440) and the linked articles for details. The kernel loader loads the binary, and if necessary, its interpreter (which is `ld.so` for dynamic binaries).
2. Each implementation of `ld.so` is format-specific.
3. Yes, either by adding a binary loader to the kernel, or by using `binfmt_misc`. See [How is Mono magical?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/259376/86440) for details.

Comment: Why the dynamic linker is named "ld.so"? I always thought ld used for linking shared libraries at load time is an executable which is used by the kernel. But going by its name, seems like it's also a shared library.

Comment: `ld` is used at build time, `ld.so` is used at run time. [`ld.so` is both a shared library and an executable.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448943/86440)