# What is "shared executables"?

Tags: executable, shared-library, elf

Stephen Kitt wrote in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448943/674

> `ld.so` is a shared ELF object, but it doesn’t require an interpreter (it
> has no .interp entry); this is typical of libraries (shared
> executables always require an interpreter; otherwise they’re static,
> not dynamic).

Is  an ELF object file  a "shared executable" if and only if it has an    `.interp` entry ?

What does "shared executables" mean? Is it the same as "shared libraries"?

Or does  "shared executables"  mean "partially linked executables"?
In CSAPP

> ```
> linux> gcc -o prog2l main2.c ./libvector.so
> ```
>
> This creates an executable object ﬁle prog2l in a form that can be linked with
> libvector.so at run time.
>
> ...
> When the loader loads and runs the executable `prog2l`, it loads the partially
> linked executable `prog2l`, using the techniques discussed in Section 7.9. Next, it
> notices that `prog2l` contains a `.interp` section, which contains the path name of
> the dynamic linker, which is itself a shared object (e.g., `ld-linux.so` on Linux
> systems).

Answer (score 2):

> Is an ELF object file a "shared executable" if and only if it has an .interp entry?

Strictly speaking, no, because it can also be a shared library. But all “shared executables” (by which I meant dynamically-linked) have an interpreter entry, regardless of their ELF type (`EXEC` or `DYN`).

> What does "shared executables" mean? Is it the same as "shared libraries"?

No, it’s not the same; I should have written “dynamically-linked executables”.

> Or does "shared executables" mean "partially linked executables"?

That’s another way of putting it.

Comment: Thanks. (1) "it can also be a shared library", do you mean a shared library which is not a "shared executable" can also have an .interp entry?  Isn't no .interp "typical of libraries"? (2) How do you tell if an ELF object file is a  “shared executable”? i.e. What necessary and sufficient condition for an ELF object file to be a "shared executable"?

Comment: (1) See `libc.so.6`. “Typical” doesn’t mean that only libraries have no `.interp` entry, or that no libraries have one. Statically-linked executables also don’t have an interpreter. (2) An ELF file is a shared executable if (a) it has ELF type `EXEC` and an `.interp` entry or (b) it has type `DYN` and the PIE flag set in `DT_FLAGS_1`.